# Wait for "any key" with Windows C in different thread

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

My main application is parsing data from an audio device which continously streams data. I want to be able to let the user press any key to stop the process where my application then will stop parsing and save all received data to a file.

The parsing loop look much like this:

```
while(1)
{
    audio_read(buf);
}
```

So consecutively, I want to listen for a key input to stop this execution. I do not want to poll for key while reading the audio data since this has to operate as fast as possible. 
I have tried reading Microsofts [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esszf9hw.aspx) but I really don't understand how to easily set up the code for executing functions in different threads.

Comment: What kind of app? GUI or console? Either way the answer is much the same. Put the audio parsing in a worker thread and handle the UI out of the main thread.

Comment: Console application, and how do I set up such a worker thread?

Comment: The Win32 API you need is `CreateThread`.

Answer (score 0):

One thread will wait for the keypress, and set a boolean flag. The thread that is processing audio data needs to periodically check to see if this flag is set.

Comment: Okey. Do you have a code example on how I can do exactly this?